# how to rebase branch from a diverged master?

Tags: git

Originally, my local master branch is the same as origin/master. imagine the follows:

1. originally

   master: a->b

   origin/master: a->b
2. origin/master one more commit

   master: a->b

   origin/master: a->b->c
3. master one more commit

   master: a->b->d

   origin/master: a->b->c
4. new branch from master

   master : a->b->d

   newbranch: a->b->d->e

   origin/master: a->b->c

I tried rebasing master branch to origin/master, I expected log of new branch will be a->b->c->d->e. But instead, log of new branch is still a->b->d->e, why is that?

Comment: Could you please write the commands that you've issued between/after the branch states you've posted so we can see where you have understood something wrong? Besides: are you sure you want to rebase `master` against `origin/master` only? What's with `newbranch`? You'll probably need `rebase --onto` for that one. (For only one commit `reset` + `cherry-pick` as proposed by 9000 is often faster.)

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do:

- Rewind local master to the last non-diverging commit *b:* `git checkout master; git reset b`
- Pull remote master: `git pull origin master`; this will pull in *c*.
- Use `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` to put commits *d* and *e* onto master, resolve any conflicts with commit *c*.

Generally it is advisable to avoid working directly on a master branch. Use feature branches, do `git pull --rebase` on them regularly to keep in sync with master, and only merge to freshly-pulled master.